# Twilio. Set Fax Webhook programmatically using the API

Tags: c#, api, twilio, fax

My application wants to dynamically purchase new FAX numbers when the pool of serviced users exceeds a certain amount.  I am able to do this programmatically from API like this (C#):

```
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Fax.V1;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;

var incomingPhoneNumber = IncomingPhoneNumberResource.Create(
  statusCallback: new Uri("https://myapp.co/api/v1/fax/twiliostatus"),
  statusCallbackMethod:Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
  pathAccountSid:"xxx",
  phoneNumber: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber(numbers[i].PhoneNumber)
  );
```

...but I don't see any mechanism for setting the value corresponding to the "A Fax Comes In" webhook (where I set method and URI) in the portal.  Is there a way I can set this from the API?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the attribute you need to set is `voiceReceiveMode`.

[IncomingPhoneNumber resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#create-an-incomingphonenumber-resource)

The configuration parameter for the new phone number to receive incoming voice calls or faxes. Can be: fax or voice and defaults to voice.